# Bash: Find, copy and rename files

Tags: bash, copy, find, rename

I am trying to copy files (on the same server) created in the last 24 hours using the filename (Unix timestamp):

```
find /srv/docs/files/ -type f -iname '*.pdf' -mtime -1 -exec cp {}   /srv/docs/pdf \;
```

However, I would like to extend this further. I would like to accomplish the following:

1. All files are named in this manner 1425787200.pdf. I would like to rename the file Sunday-0400.pdf
2. I would would like to create a new directory /srv/docs/pdf/day/time/ .

A file named 1425787200.pdf would end up in /srv/docs/pdf/Sunday/0400/Sunday-0400.pdf

Additionally, if the file already exists, an incremental number should be added to the file. eg Sunday-0400-1.pdf, Sunday-0400-2.pdf

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you get Sunday at 0400 from 1425787200?

Comment: 1425787200 is a Unix timestamp.  It can be converted to a Sun, 08 Mar 2015 04:00:00 +0000. I used an online time convertor for that. I am not sure how that would be accomplished using bash.

Comment: There are three different "Unix timestamps" on each file.  None of them track creation time!  You are looking for the phrase "seconds from epoch".

Comment: Thanks for the comment @William. There is a separate process that creates the .pdf files and names it based on the time it was created. What I'm hoping to do is retrieve the day and time from the filename and use that to organize the files.

Answer (score 1):

To change file name `1425787200.pdf` to `/srv/docs/pdf/Sunday/0400/Sunday-0400.pdf` use something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
file=1425787200.pdf
day=$(date +"%A" -d "@${file%.*}")
time=$(date +"%H%M" -d "@${file%.*}")
new_file=/srv/docs/pdf/$day/$time/$day-$time.pdf
if [ -e "$new_file" ]; then
    num_file=${new_file%.*}
    num=1
    while [ -e "${num_file}-${num}.pdf" ]; do
        num=$(( num + 1 ))
    done
    new_file=${num_file}-${num}.pdf
fi
mv $file $new_file
```

this will also number duplcates.

Comment: You are incrementing `n` but using `num_file` and `num`.

Comment: Thanks @PaulEvans. I ran the script. Initially was getting errors like this  mv: cannot move `1425787200.pdf' to `/srv/docs/pdf/Sunday/0930/Sunday-0930.pdf': No such file or directory.
 
 I ended up creating the folders listed in the error message manually and it worked.

However the issue is that the date and time being used is the current, not the one when the file was created.

Comment: My apologies @PaulEvans. I have tried a few different files from different days and it works. Thank you so much. I still have to create output folders manually but thats not a big deal                             Now need to figure out loooping through the files in the folder.

Comment: @kingsmen you can simply add after `$day` and `$time` are created (and before the `mv`): `if [ ! -e /srv/docs/pdf/$day/$time ]; then mkdir -p /srv/docs/pdf/$day/$time; fi` to create the output folders

Comment: Thanks @PaulEvans. and to add a loop for all pdfs in the directory....something like this ?                                               for file in 'find /srv/docs/files/ -type f -iname '*.pdf' -mtime -1'; do

Comment: Thanks @PaulEvans once again. and to add a loop for all pdfs in the directory....something like this ?                                               for file in 'find /srv/docs/files/ -type f -iname '*.pdf' -mtime -1'; do ; echo $(file)

Comment: @kingsmen yes, something like that should scoop up your files of interest in a nice driving `for` loop